# How to overlap a border in CSS in order to create tabs?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create the following tabs:

[image]

And have a problem figuring out how to make the `active` tab overlap the order on the list. Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li class="active">LATEST</li>
 <li>VOTES</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: have you tried to `z-index` your elements? You need to set a `position` for `z-index` to work.

Comment: Why do you need overlapping? you only need selective border depending on class usage

Comment: @Amit I need a border on the entire `ul` (in order to have the full width bottom border) -- not just on the `li` buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Without div:**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/790/

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#f0f0f0
}
ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
ul:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
    content:"";
    top: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
ul:after {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    content:""
}
ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #777;
    margin-right:-1px;
    position:relative;
}
ul li.active {
    border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f0
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">LATEST</li>
    <li>VOTES</li>
</ul>
```

**With extra div**

You can try this way: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/787/

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#f0f0f0
}
ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;
}
ul:after {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    content:""
}
ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #777;
    margin-right:-1px;
    position:relative;
}
div {
    border:1px solid #777;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
ul li.active {
    border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f0
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">LATEST</li>
    <li>VOTES</li>
</ul>
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: Would be great to be able to do this without a content div

Comment: @K K Silly side question: should it be `:` or `::` for the pseudo elements? For some reason the single colon doesn't work in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @K K Another silly question: why is the `content=""` needed here? I'm sorry for asking such basic questions.

Comment: @user3188544 Basically, when you use :before,:after or any other pseudo element you create a dynamic element. When creating these, you need to specify their content. Without content property the pseudo elements will not reflect in the DOM. Regarding :: and : ,  refer this http://www.d.umn.edu/~lcarlson/csswork/selectors/pseudo_dif.html . It will clear your doubts

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hide the bottom border of the active link instead?

```
.active{
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Or make it transparent:

```
.active{
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Setting border to 0 will cause flickering

Comment: @KK , but making it transparent will do it

Comment: Yeah. You should change the color rather than the dimension.

Comment: I need a border on the entire `ul` (in order to have the full width bottom border) -- not just on the `li` buttons. So this wouldn't work.