# Strange Negative Margin Overlap Behavior

Tags: css, tabs

I can't post the code for several reasons, but basically I am trying to create tabs similar to [How to overlap a border in CSS in order to create tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585707/how-to-overlap-a-border-in-css-in-order-to-create-tabs). The problem I am running into is that the -1px margin is behaving strangely in my application as seen here.

[image]

A margin of 0px places the border of the content below the border of the tabs as expected, but a margin of -1px jumps what appears to be 1.5px. This doesn't make any sense to me and I have never encountered it before. Considering the posted examples work just fine in my browser, there must be a style in my application that is interfering somewhere. Obviously without code I can't ask for help fixing my specific issue, but what could possibly cause this kind of behavior?

EDIT: I realized that I have the default zoom on Chrome set to 125%. When I reset the zoom to 100%, it works perfectly as expected. So I guess the question now is why zoom is affecting my application but not the sample linked above?

Answer (score 0):

thats because the tabs are centered in the div. if you use cntrl scroll to affect the view then it will correct.

ALSO.. you CAN put the border on the div container instead of the content div which will fix that problem.

you are basically down one level.